# Summons with spontaneous casting casting low level spells in higher level slots

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, summoning

When summoned creatures have spell casting abilities which are spontaneous in nature like sorcerers, are you allowed to have them cast lower level spells in higher level slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of why they in particular wouldn't be able to, but it is important to remember that summons can't use their own summons, or spells with valuable material components.

Comment: I do remember that, but in cases where they have damage spells or healing spells, those might be put to better use than something else